# Finding the equation of a parabola given conditions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I cant find a way to find the equation of the parabola, first its given that the vertex is on the line $2x+y-5=0$; focus on the line $3x-y-21=0$; directrix on $x=2$.

already tried graphing the lines which the vertex and focus are in but I cant seem to find where they are. I'm stuck

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Let $(x_S;y_S)$ be the coordinates of  the vertex $S$, $(x_F,y_F)$ the coordinates of the focus $F$, $(2,y_H)$ the coordinates of the common projection of $S$  and $F$ onto the directrix.

We know that $H$ and $F$ are symmetric w.r.t. $S$, so $\;2+x_F=2x_H\;$ and $\;y=y_S=y_F$. Taking into account the equations of the lines on which $S$ and $F$ live, we  obtain
$$2+\frac{y+21}3=5-y.$$